# Visual Form Inheritance not working for Smart Device/Compact Framework in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework

When I try to create an Inherited Form for a Windows CE application in Visual Studio 2008, I get the error message:

The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: TestForm --- The base class 'InheritanceTest.BaseForm' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.

Visual Studio 2008, Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1.

I can get the problem without writing any code at all, and without customising the form in any way. It doesn't make a difference whether the BaseForm is in the same project or in a separate class library. The project compiles ok, the problem is with viewing the inherited form in the designer. It occurs on both of my computers. I'm using C#.

Procedure to get the problem:
File - New Project - Windows C# - Smart Device - CeInheritanceTest (.Net Framework 3.5)
Target Platform - Windows CE - Device Application
Add – New Item - Visual C# Items – Windows Forms – Windows Form – "BaseForm"
Build Solution
Add – New Item - Visual C# Items – Windows Forms – Inherited Form – "TestForm"
 - inherit from BaseForm

If I do the same thing for a normal desktop app, form inheritance works no problem.

From searching the web for this problem, it looks like others are getting form inheritance to work using the compact framework, so I must be missing something.

I have not written or modified any code, so the base class is not abstract, and I am not using PInvoke.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64-bit. I have just tried it on an old 32-bit XP machine and it all works. So it seems the problem might relate to 64-bit environment. It it possible to get form inheritance working for the Compact Framework on a 64-bit development machine?

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because the designer metadata for .NET CF controls is not automatically created and compiled into your project in order to keep the binary size down for devices. You have to manually create what's called a "design-time attribute file".

In the project that contains your base form, add a new item. Choose "Design-Time Attribute File" from the list of installed templates. It will have a .xmta extension. If you open it, you'll notice it's an xml file. There are a whole slew of options you can add to this file to control how your custom controls / forms should be designed and serialized, and you can look up more information about this, but if you just want to be able to design your form you only have to add one attribute: DesktopCompatible=True.

Here's a sample:

```
<Classes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/03/SmartDevices/XMTA.xsd">
  <Class Name="CeInheritanceTest.BaseForm">    
    <DesktopCompatible>true</DesktopCompatible>
 </Class>
</Classes>
```

Ensure that the name in the "Class" node is the fully qualified name of your base form. Compile your project and you should be able to open it up in the designer. You'll also notice that there is a new assembly in your project's output folder with a .asmmeta.dll extension. This is the assembly that contains the designer support for the library with the designable components. Visual Studio automatically loads this when attempting to design .NET CF components.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried adding the .xmta file but it hasn't made any difference. I have found some documentation on this, and I also tried adding DesktopCompatible(true) as a Custom Attribute in the class diagram, which has much the same effect, but to no avail. I'll see if I can find some more documentation on this in the morning.

Comment: @urtlet adding a custom attribute in the class file won't help for .NET CF components. The xmta file ought to resolve your issue. Are you certain that the class name you recorded in the file is the fully-qualified name of your base class?

Comment: I tried adding the .xmta file directly, as you described, and I checked the qualified name carefully, but it didn't make any difference. Then I tried adding DesktopCompatible(true) as a CustomAttribute to the class **diagram** - this actually creates an xmta file when you're using compact framework. Then I discovered that the problem only occurs on my 64-bit machines; visual form inheritance works for me on an old 32-bit XP machine, and on a 32-bit Windows 7 VM. And it works without having to add the xmta file. It appears that the problem is related to my dev machines being 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to find solution for this problem too and I finally solved it.
Besides adding  true
to base form you should add following to Load method of the base form:

```
if (this.Site != null && this.Site.DesignMode == true)
{
  // Design Mode
}
else
{
  // Run-time
}
```

which prevents code in the Load event handler from being executed by the designer.
One more thing, if in the inherited form Designer.cs next is added

this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.BaseForm_Load);
this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.BaseForm_Closing);

delete these lines otherwise you will get an error
at System.ComponentModel.Design.ServiceContainer.AddService(Type serviceType, ServiceCreatorCallback callback, Boolean promote)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer. What are you setting to true on the base form? Did you already have a Load event handler on your base form that you modified or did you add a Load event handler with some code in it? (In my simple test, I didn't have any event handlers on either base form or inherited form). Have you been able to get the form designer working for an inherited form in a Windows CE app in VS 2008 on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear. What you should set to true is base form custom attribute. Easiest way to do it is to open the class diagram, drag your base form to it, click on your base form and in the opened properties window type DesktopCompatible(true) at custom attributes. For load and closing events handler, I created them myself for thr base form. For inherited form, I don't remember if they were generated or I created them myself but they should be deleted

Comment: I think we might have different situations. I had already tried using the DesktopCompatible(true) attribute and it didn't help. I get the problem with no event handlers at all.
I've just done some more testing and still cannot get the designer to show the inherited form on my 64-bit machines.
Instead of clarifying your answer in a comment, I think it is better to edit your answer.